# Unsigned right shift assignment in JS forEach loop

Tags: javascript, arrays, implementation

I found an implementation of javascript forEach loop and one thing bothers me.

```
if (!Array.prototype.forEach) {
Array.prototype.forEach = function(fun /*, thisp*/) {
    var len = this.length >>> 0;
    if (typeof fun != "function") {
        throw new TypeError();
    }

    var thisp = arguments[1];
    for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        if (i in this) {
            fun.call(thisp, this[i], i, this);
        }
    }
};
}
```

What is the point of unsigned right shift `this.length >>> 0`?

Answer (score 1):

It's a way to ensure that `len` is a an 32 bits unsigned integer.

By using `>>> 0` you can never get `NaN` or negative values.

Comment: This makes sense. I was thinking for a while what if there is somehow a negative value and the output will be a huge number, but then I found out that the next statement ```if (i in this)``` prevents the error of non-existing index in array. Thanks!